# High gain amplifier ADA4528

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, gain

I am trying to make an amplifier which should amplify signals from at least 10uV (lower better) to around 100mV or above. The signals range from a few Hz to around 100kHz. Adjustable gain is also helpful. I was planning to use ADA4528 for this. Please give some suggestions on this. Also, is ADA4528 a suitable choice? If not, please suggest some opamps which might help achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: What is your signal to noise ratio? How much noise is acceptable in your application?

Comment: You could use 4 stages with gain of 10. Noise is not particularly low on that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a ratio of 10uV to 100mV you'll need a gain of 10000. Looking at the closed loop Gain vs Frequency graph if you extrapolate the gain to 10k, you'll have a bandwidth of roughly 100Hz. There can be gain, and bandwidth, but there is a tradeoff between the two. If the bandwidth of the signal really is more than 100Hz you'll need more than one amplification stage.

For example, you could use two 4528's with a gain of 100, and a bandwidth of ~10kHz

or as Sphero suggested a 4 stages of 10 (or two ADA4528-2's or dual opamp packages) which would give you a bandwidth of 100kHz

[image]

Another thing that I'd recommend is use the ADA4522 as the 4528 requires an RF input filter (the 4522 has the RF input filter built in).

Comment: Aside from BW issues, with a gain of 10K, the OP also needs to be concerned about input offset parameters.  Too high and the amp will obviously saturate.  This amplifier has an input offset about a half order of magnitude below the input signal size (should be OK).  Of course DC offset on the input signal must also be very small.